# configuring intellij with terraform plugin to connect to aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, intellij-idea, terraform

I need to be able to run the terraform plugin to do standard terraform tasks such as terraform plan and terraform apply which would require aws connectivity. i have installed the terrafom plugin but have no idea how to configure it

Comment: What plugin for intellij do you have that is meant to run terraform?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform Plugin released in JetBrains plugin community is used for HashiCorp Terraform / HCL language support for doing stuffs like:

- Syntax highlighting.
- Code formatter with the 'Reformat code'.
- Report usage of deprecated properties.

And **NOT** as a substitute for executing terraform binary.

Reference: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7808-hashicorp-terraform--hcl-language-support

Comment: I am using this plugin and the code formatter doesn't indent the code as in terraform docs... do you know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
I've installed terraform [using chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/terraform)

1. Set the path in settings

[image]

from `terraform.exe`
[image]
to `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\terraform.exe`

[image]

Intellij will still display it as `terraform.exe` but it will now work.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin now supports your requested commands (plan\apply), make sure you update it.

Regarding Arcones question: the plugin is maintained by Vladislav Rassokhin, therefore we might experience latency in the plugin support for new Terraform features. You may open an issue here: https://github.com/VladRassokhin/intellij-hcl/issues